# OF and CF status when multiply two numbers

Tags: flags

When two numbers multiply, what happens to the O (Overflow flag register) and C (Carry flag register) flag bits?

Answer (score 0):

After **multiplying two 8-bit** numbers OF and CF will be set if an overflow occurs. That's when the result is:

- above 255 if you use the MUL instruction

and when the result is

- above 127 if you use the IMUL instruction and the operands had had the same sign or
- below -128 and the operands had had two different signs

The overflow will be stored automatically to ah, so AX will be al*[the 2nd source register]. ah will be zeroed, if no overflow occurs.

After **multiplying AX with a 16-bit number** OF and CF will be set if the result is:

- above 65535 if you use the MUL instruction

and when the result is

- above 32767 if you use the IMUL instruction and the operands had had the same sign or
- below -32768 if you use the IMUL instruction and the operands had had two different signs

The overflow will be stored automatically to DX.